# How to use: System.Collections.Concurrent

Tags: c#, concurrent-queue

I am trying to add `using System.Collections.Concurrent` and it is not working.

> The type or namespace name 'Concurrent' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Collections' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: Did you add a reference (System.Collections.Concurrent) in your project ?

Comment: I was using .net 3.5..... I have since changed it to 4.5 and is now working. If someone wants to write answer feel free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is only available from .NET 4. Upgrade your project to at least .NET 4.0.